# Bone not able to be named?

Tags: game-engine, rigging

I have a quick question: when I was making some adjustments to my weapon, I removed a vertex group because the bone was lost (I don't know how), and I basically made a new bone. I used weight paint and set it all up, and tried to finish it by naming it the previous bone's name. It keeps adding .001, .002 (, etc) every time I try to name it. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old bone is still there it is on another layer to see all armature layers go to Properties_Editor->Data->Skeleton and select a layer (or hold shift and select multiple) :

[image]

to move the bone to another layer you select the bone from the view(if visible) or from the Outliner ,then go to Properties_Editor->Bone->Relations->layers and select a layer :

[image]